# Where is the key file path actually pointing to?

Tags: azure-data-factory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-bigquery?tabs=data-factory

What is "Key file path" here? Do I upload my GSA json key somewhere? What "path" is this? I was expected to just plugin in my json key text somewhere.

## EDIT

I tried using my local path `/Users/me/Downloads/mykey.json` and even tried moving it to temp `/tmp/mykey.json` but I get this

```
error:
Error code
9603
Details
ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC] (10380) Unable to establish connection with data source. Missing settings: {[KeyFilePath_Enc]}
Activity ID: sdfsdfsdfsdf.
```

Comment: Could you please add the information about which activity are you using and expected result with pipeline picture for better understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in that [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-bigquery?tabs=data-factory#using-service-authentication) page, if you need to use Service Authentication:

> This authentication type can be used only on Self-hosted Integration
> Runtime.

So that file path is a file path on the self-hosted runtime VM for the integration runtime the Google BigQuery linked service is associated in your ADF.

Also in the example JSON just below that it clarifies:

> "keyFilePath": "<.p12 or .json key path on the IR machine>"